# How to create an object instance of class with internal constructor via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, instance

**Example:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass));
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    internal MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

> **System.MissingMethodException**
>
> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

**Solution:**

```
var myClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass), nonPublic:true);
```

I cannot understand, why I cannot create an instance inside the assembly with internal constructor. This constructor should be available inside the execution assembly. It should work like public for this assembly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating a constructor with parameters in an internal class with reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077253/instantiating-a-constructor-with-parameters-in-an-internal-class-with-reflection)

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654702/invoke-internal-extern-constructor-using-reflections

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not that impossible. you've to tell it is not a public.

```
var myClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass), true);//say nonpublic
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor inside your MyClass is Internal try to change to public

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

or

Pass true to CreateInstance

```
var myClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass),true );
```