# Instantiate Type with internal Constructor with reflection

Tags: c#, constructor, internal, system.reflection, .net-standard

I have a factory class that needs to instantiate an unknown class.
It does it as so:

```
public class Factory
{
    public void SetFoo(Type f)
    {
        Activator.CreateInstance(f);
    }
}
```

Problem is I'd like that constructor to be internal, but marking it internal gives me a MissingMethodException, but the constructor is in the same assembly. 
if it's set to puclic it works fine.

I've tried the solutions provided here
[How to create an object instance of class with internal constructor via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240971/how-to-create-an-object-instance-of-class-with-internal-constructor-via-reflecti)

and here
[Instantiating a constructor with parameters in an internal class with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077253/instantiating-a-constructor-with-parameters-in-an-internal-class-with-reflection)

which translates to doing as such:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(f,true)
```

but no success...

I'm using NETStandard.Library (1.6.1) with System.Reflection (4.3.0)

**Update:**

the answers provided at the time of this update pointed me in the right direction:

```
var ctor = f.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

var instance = (f)ctor[0].Invoke(null);
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(f,true)` works fine for me with an internal constructor. Can you provide an [reproducable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does the constructor expect some parameters ?

Comment: Is the `Factory` class define in a different assembly than the type of F?

Comment: @Matias no parameters.

Comment: @Michael it's in the same assembly just different namespace

Answer (score 22, accepted):

BindingFlags:

```
var ctor = typeof(MyType).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).FirstOrDefault(c => !c.GetParameters().Any());

var instance = (MyType)ctor.Invoke(new object[0]);
```

The BindingFlags gets the non public constructors. The specific constructor is found via specified parameter types (or rather the lack of parameters). Invoke calls the constructor and returns the new instance.

Comment: .NET Core does not have a GetConstructor method that takes two parameters.

Comment: here I get No overload for 'GetConstructor' takes 4 arguments.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to find the constructor:

```
var ctor = typeof(MyType).GetTypeInfo().GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(x => /*filter by the parameter types*/);
var instance = ctor.Invoke(parameters) as MyType;
```

Please add a reference to the System.Reflection namespace.

Comment: for the GetInfo().GetConstructors... I get 'Type info does not contain a definition for GetConstructors()

Comment: An example of /*filter by the parameter types*/ would be helpful.

Comment: @Grisha: var ctor = typeof(Target).GetTypeInfo().GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 1 && x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(Target));

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the constructor via reflection, and invoke it.

```
var ctor = typeof(Test)
    .GetConstructors(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
        BindingFlags.Public | 
        BindingFlags.Instance
    )
    .First();
var instance = ctor.Invoke(null) as Test;
```

Comment: you may want to filter out to parameter less constructor, else may run into `ArgumentNullExceptions` i.e. `.GetConstructors().First(c=>c.GetParameters().Length==0)`

Comment: @zafar The example in the question does not have a parameterless constructor. And the answer is more to show how it is done.